# php ZMQ push integration over http

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, zeromq, pushstate

Im am trying to implement push integration using php and native zmq. I have successfully send send my message to server, but my problem is I cannot push the message to browser using js Websocket(). I says ***WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Invalid status line***

here is my code for client:

```
<?php
 try {
   function send($data) {
      $context = new ZMQContext();
      $push = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH);
      $push->connect("tcp://localhost:5555");

      $push->send($data);
    }    

    if(isset($_POST["username"])) {
      $envelope = array(
        "from" => "client",
        "to" => "owner",
        "msg" => $_POST["username"]
      );
      send(json_encode($envelope)); # send the data to server
    }
 }
 catch( Exception $e ) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
 }

?>
```

Client

here is my server:

```
$context = new ZMQContext();

$pull = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$pull->bind("tcp://*:5555"); #this will be my pull socket from client

$push = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH);
$push->bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:8080"); # this will be the push socket to owner

while(true) {
    $data = $pull->recv(); # when I receive the data decode it
    $parse_data = json_decode($parse_data);

    if($parse_data["to"] == "owner") {
        $push->send($parse_data["msg"]); # forward the data to the owner
    }
    printf("Recieve: %s.\n", $data);
}
```

and here is my owner.php i'm expecting the data to be send thru Websocket in browser:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Message</h2>
    <ul id="messagelog">
    </ul>
    <script>
        var logger = document.getElementById("messagelog");
        var conn = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080"); # the error is pointing here.

        conn.onOpen = function(e) {
            console.log("connection established");
        }
        conn.onMessage = function(data) {
            console.log("recieved: ", data);
        }

        conn.onError = function(e) {
            console.log("connection error:", e);
        }
        conn.onClose = function(e) {
            console.log("connection closed~");
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Please do tell me what I am missing. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot connect a websocket to a zmq socket*, they are different communication protocols (a websocket is more like a traditional socket, a zmq socket is more of an abstraction that adds extra features).  You need to set up a way on your server to receive a websocket connection.

*You *may* be able to make this work using RAW socket types, but that's a bit more advanced and shouldn't be entered into unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't establish a protocol communication at all. You managed to receive the message, but you never confirmed, by parsing it and sending appropriate response, that your server is indeed a WebSocket server.

Since you are already using PHP and ZeroMQ, the easiest way out is to use [Mongrel2](http://mongrel2.org/) which is, among other things, capable of understanding WebSocket protocol and deliver it to a ZeroMQ endpoint encoded as a tnetstring (a json-like encoding format, trivial to parse).

The other solution is to fully support the WebSocket protocol in your code - something that's outside of the scope of this question and answer.